# Leveling system discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I need help with leveling system on discord.py.
I know that the verification is a bug with `async def add_experience` but I don't know how to fix it. I am just asking someone to explain to me what a pity the whole code is

````
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.bot == False:
        with open('users.json', 'r') as f:
            users = json.load(f)

       
        lastMessage[message.author.id] = time.time()
        await add_experience(users, message.author, 6)
        await update_data(users, message.author)
        await level_up(users, message.author, message)
        

        with open('users.json', 'w') as f:
            json.dump(users, f)

          

    await client.process_commands(message)



async def add_experience(users, user, exp):
  if time.time() - lastMessage[user.id] > 300:
  users[f'{user.id}']['experience'] += exp


async def update_data(users, user):
    if not f'{user.id}' in users:
        users[f'{user.id}'] = {}
        users[f'{user.id}']['experience'] = 0
        users[f'{user.id}']['level'] = 1





async def level_up(users, user, message):
    with open('levels.json', 'r') as g:
        levels = json.load(g)
    experience = users[f'{user.id}']['experience']
    lvl_start = users[f'{user.id}']['level']
    lvl_end = int(experience ** (1 / 4))
    if lvl_start < lvl_end:
        await message.channel.send(f'{user.mention} Awansowałes na level {lvl_end}. Gratulacje!')
        users[f'{user.id}']['level'] = lvl_end

@client.command()
async def level(ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
    if not member:
        id = ctx.message.author.id
        with open('users.json', 'r') as f:
            users = json.load(f)
        lvl = users[id]['level']
        await ctx.send(f'Posiadasz aktualnie {lvl} level.')
    else:
        id = member.id
        with open('users.json', 'r') as f:
            users = json.load(f)
        lvl = users[id]['level']
        await ctx.send(f'{member} is at level {lvl}!')
    ```
````

Comment: The obvious problem with `add_experience` is that the indentation is wrong.

Comment: `lastMessage` is not defined in `add_experience()` Furthermore if you are reusig `lastMessage` `time.time()` is immediately evaluated twice which means it will be never bigger than 300 (seconds). So that `if` condition always fails.

Answer (score 0):

A compile of the possible issues here:

Python is pity with indents, make sure it's all well-indented, and it's all either tabs or 4 spaces.

According to Tin, yes, you have to somehow define/pass into the variable lastMessage, otherwise that'll be another error (If there are any after, make sure to comment them here too!).

Third, just as a readability thing, maybe define `user` as `users[user.id]`, that'll let you not have to put two "[]" in a roll, but that's more on the level of personal preference.